# how to store value in database selected in dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

this is my action of controller class

```
 public ActionResult checking()
        {
            rikuEntities db = new rikuEntities();
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.emp.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.name,
                Text = c.name
            });
            ViewBag.saan = items;

            return View();

    }
```

Now i want to use this dropdownlist value in my UserCreate.cshtml.
when i select a value from dropdownlist values and press submit then that value should store in another table student.
please suggest me what should i do for it ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to define your form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
     @HTML.DropDownList("SomeName", (SelectList)ViewBag.saan)
     <input type="submit" value="save" />
}
```

Then in your post controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult checking(string SomeName)
{
   ...
}
```